# Will I be able to use Find iPhone if my battery is dead?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

Will the location of my iPhone be updated if the battery is dead? Is there any way to know if the battery on my iPhone has died?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS 7 and a newer version of Find My Phone/iCloud, the battery level is reported so you can know approximately how much longer the tracking might be active without a recharge.

When this question was asked, the battery level was not shown so the answer then was no.

Either way, once your iPhone runs out of power, it will shut itself off. There is residual power left in the phone to run the screen and respond to buttons for a while, but once that last remaining power drains, eventually the voltage in the battery is not sufficient to run even the button sensing part of the device.

Plugging it into power will re-start your phone and once it establishes a network connection, find my phone will resume.

In your case - if Find My Phone says your device is not found - you can't really tell if it was turned off by intention or automatically or has lost network connectivity (by having a SIM removed or just being out of range).

Comment: Thx bmike. Fwiw, it's possible to know retroactively if the phone has died and been found/charged by activating the "Notify me if my found is found" feature on Find My IPhon

Comment: You'll only know it is back in contact, but not why it left the network. Perhaps you could piece things together with diagnostic log forensics after the device is recovered, but that's not really part of find my phone. Do let us know how this ends up for you and the iPhone :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have lost my phone as well, but without the internet, I have a tip for discharged phone finding. One tip is to find the phone in the least obvious places ( start with your house). I actually found my phone in the artificial tree at our house! (Not really expected). Hope this tip helps!